# use recursion to find if a user is the referrer of another user php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this problem for two days and i still couldn't come up with a solution. I an currently designing a website where a user can by the mean of his memberid register other users so that we can allow him points.One of the main game in the site requires that if a user has registered two other users his percentage equals 1.then the function must recursively check for each of those two users if they also have registered two users each then increase the percentage to 3.So for each level found apart from the 1st ,percentage must be incremented by two;

Here is a little diagram to show you ho it is suppose to work:

```
                                             [A]
                                    [B]             [C]
                                  [D] [E]         [F] [G]
                                [H][I] [j][k]   [l][m] [o][p]
```

A represents the member we want to find the percentage for.He registers [B] and[C] his percentage=1
B registers [D] and [E] percentage+=1.C registers [F] and [G]here also percentage+=1.So at this level of checking percentage will be equal to 3.

here is the function i came up with but its incomplete and im pretty sure it wont work.am stuck please help me.

```php
function calcpercentage($id)
 {
  $count=0;
  $percent=1;
  $id1=$id;
  $sql="SELECT * from bs100049 WHERE RefId='$id1'";
  $checkh=mysql_query($sql) or die('error'.mysql_error());
  while($result=mysql_fetch_array($checkh)&& $count<=2)
  {
   $count++;
   $id1=$result['MemberId'];
   $percent++;
  }
 }
```

As i am also working with mysql it doesnt make it easy. Am sure though once i figure out the function I'll be able to write a function to draw that tree above dynamically for each user.

here is a better explanation(i wanted to post this after Dan's answer but i couldnt)
here is how this site am designing works.you can register only if an existing member is your referrer so in the "member" table your id and the referer's will be stored. in this format (id,name,memberid,refid).once you are registered you can apply to participate in different games.the bs100049 game requires that you make a purchase and register 2 users yourself.once this is done you can be sure that you already earn 1%.if and only if both your registered users have completed what you did above(each of them has registered two users ) then percentage increments from 1 to 3 and so
the next value of percentage will be 5 and so on .if a user has made a purchase for the bs100049 game,he is automatically stored  in the bs100049 table even though he doesnt have any registered users yet so if he queries to see what is his current percentage it' ll be 1%...

Comment: One more thing that I can't tell from your description. How many points does A get if B referred two people but C did not? Will A have 2 points or 1 point?

Comment: if B referred two people and C did not then we stop the search.both must have referred at least 2 for the calculation to go on so i think A will be stuck to 1 point

Comment: i havent tried the itterative way yet as i was and still am pretty convinced that this must be dealt with through recursion but it's been two days now that i started working on this algorithm and time 's running thin for me... thanks for ur help Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my approach. Please note that you should consider switching to PDO or mysqli as the mysql functions are deprecated. For the sake of the example I have used them though. You also have to make sure that your data indeed forms a tree because otherwise you will run into an infinite loop.

If you can avoid the recursion try to.

I am assuming that the id of the referred user exists in the table in a column called id. I also assume that there can never be more than two referred users and limit them at 2.

```
function calc($id) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bs100049 WHERE RefId='$id' LIMIT 2";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 2) {
        // We have two referred users (1 point) and if calc returns 1 we add 1 for each user.

        $user1 = mysql_result($res, 0, 'id');
        $user2 = mysql_result($res, 1, 'id');

        return 1 + (1 * calc($user1)) + (1 * calc($user2));
    }
    // If we get here we have 0 or 1 referred users.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im home now and ill try your function Dan.here is how this site am designing works.you can register only if an existing member is your referrer so in the "member" table your id and the referer's will be stored.

Comment: That might require another approach then because basically the tree can be have different widths at each level, right? Or is there a limit on how many users a user can refer?

Comment: yes the limit is two for each user.the table bs100049 does not accept duplicate users.check my first post ive added a more detailed explanation.all users are stored in the member table and if a user subscribe to  this game even if he has registered 100 users ,if two of them are found in the table the percentage =1.we repeat the same process for those two users that have been found(check if each of their memberid is found at least twice in the refid column of the bs100049 table) and increments percentage of the top member in the tree if found.i know it's quite complicated for me.thx Dan

Comment: finally i tested your function with a little modification it gave me the results i wanted to see thanx again Dan

Answer (score 0):

I think for it to be recursive you first must define the end case - when a user has NOT registered 2 users:

```
function calcpercentage($id){

    //SQL to get $count (number of users this user has referred) + also array of usr ids at this 'level'

    foreach($usr_ids as $usr_id){

        if($count<2){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return 1+calcpercentage($usr_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The return will cause the function to return a value after the first foreach loop and as such only check the first user in the array.

Comment: yes that is pretty much it...ill check it out once i am home if it works ill use the same algorithm to draw each tree..thanx jeremy